# How do you reduce the scrollable height of a div with scaled content?

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, transform

I have a scrollable div that I zoom/scale the content of using css3 transform. It works fine if I'm zooming in (scaling up the content) but I've noticed that when scaling down, below 100%, the amount that you can scroll vertically of the container div does not reduce.

I've made [a jsfiddle to illustrate this](http://jsfiddle.net/SrJ59/1/)

CSS:

```
.scrollable
{
    height: 250px;
    width: 250px;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: green;
}

.content
{
    height :500px;
    width : 500px;
    background: linear-gradient(red, blue);
    ...
}
```

JS/jquery:

```
function scaleContent(newScale){
    var $content = $("#content");
    var scaleString = "scale("+newScale+")";
    //var height = (newScale<1)? $("#content").height()/scale*newScale : originalHeight;
    $content.css({
    '-webkit-transform' : scaleString,
    '-webkit-transform-origin' : '0 0',
    ...
    //'height' : height +'px'
    });
    scale=newScale;
}
```

The actual scaling and the amount that you can scroll horizontally works perfectly, but the amount you can scroll vertically doesn't change below 100%.

Note: the amount you can scroll vertically appears to change on the first scaledown/zoomout, but this is simply because the horizontal scrollbar is removed.

I tried to manually change the height of the content, but this just messed with the content dimensions (duh). That's the commented-out height code.

The ellipses are where I've repeated things for other browsers.

Comment: Clarification following answer by @sissy :

I want the scrollable container div to stay the same size, but the internal div to scale in size. The problem is that if you scale down the content, the vertical scrollbar of the container does not get any smaller, so you can scroll for the length original unscaled content.

I can see the confusion is from my wording. When I said the "scrollable height" I meant that height that you could scroll, not the height of the element called scrollable.

I'll edit the wording of my question.

Comment: I've added my own answer that uses another div to wrap the content and restricts the view of the content. It's not ideal because I don't really want to add any more complexity to my DOM, so I'm still open to any better answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've managed to come up with one solution, though it's probably not the best. I introduced another div around the content, which I call the view wrapper. I set its overflow to "hidden" and manually set its width and height to match what the scaled content should be.

CSS:

```
.viewwrapper{
    height :500px;
    width : 500px;
    overflow: hidden
}
```

JS:

```
function scaleContent(newScale){
    var $content = $("#content");
    var scaleString = "scale("+newScale+")";
    var $viewwrapper = $("#viewwrapper");
    var height = $content.height()/newScale;
    var width = $content.width()/newScale;
    $viewwrapper.height(height);
    $viewwrapper.width(width);
    $content.css({
        '-webkit-transform' : scaleString,
        '-webkit-transform-origin' : '0 0',
    ...
    });
}
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SrJ59/54/)

**Update:**

This won't work if you're using jQuery 3.0 or 3.1. The read behaviour of the height and width functions has changed, so they return the scaled values. To fix the above code for those versions you can just say.

```
function scaleContent(newScale){
    var $content = $("#content");
    var scaleString = "scale("+newScale+")";
    var $viewwrapper = $("#viewwrapper");
    $viewwrapper.height($content.height());
    $viewwrapper.width($content.width());
    $content.css({
        '-webkit-transform' : scaleString,
        '-webkit-transform-origin' : '0 0',
    ...
    });
}
```

[JSFiddle using jQuery 3.0](http://jsfiddle.net/JoolsCaesar/SrJ59/69/)

[However this probably won't make it into future versions of jQuery.](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/3193)

Update 2:
You might see unnecessary scrollbars in Chrome when you zoom out of the content. This is [down to a Chrome bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=633602).

Answer (score 0):

you're applying transformations to your #content div, but the outside div, #scrollable has also a fixed height and is not reducing. You have to apply transformations to it too.

Because if you're zooming in, the outside div adapts to the inside content, whereas if you're reducing it does not.

Comment: Edit: my last comment was nonsense:
Scaling the scrollable causes the scrollable to change size. :-/ Did you mean something else?
http://jsfiddle.net/SrJ59/4/

Comment: "Because if you're zooming in, the outside div adapts to the inside content, whereas if you're reducing it does not."
That's another thing that's strange to me; It actually does for width, but just not for height.

Comment: No that's what i meant, what you did in your last fiddle. Seems ok now or maybe i misunderstood your question. About the height not reducing seems a little strange, dunno why.

Comment: No, sorry, that's not it. 
I want the scrollable container div to stay the same size, but the internal div to scale in size. The problem is that if you scale down the content, the vertical scrollbar of the container does not get any smaller, so you can scroll for the length original unscaled content.

I can see the confusion is from my wording. When I said the "scrollable height" I meant that height that you could scroll, not the height of the element called scrollable.